# HTML data rendering in the textfield - Jasper

Tags: html, jasper-reports

I am having the below sample text in the oracle db stored as string. I am showing this text in a textfield with markup language set as "html". The space between each paragraphs mentioned here is 10 point is not seen while exporting in PDF. My thought is that CSS style "line-height" is not read by Jasper. Can anyone could help in acheiving the solution with any customization?

Changes

This is the sample text for testing purpose. This is the sample text for testing purpose. This is the sample text for testing purpose. This is the sample text for testing purpose. This is the sample text for testing purpose. This is the sample text for testing purpose. This is the sample text for testing purpose. 

The idea of sample text for testing purpose. The idea of sample text for testing purpose. The idea of sample text for testing purpose. The idea of sample text for testing purpose. The idea of sample text for testing purpose. The idea of sample text for testing purpose. The idea of sample text for testing purpose. The idea of sample text for testing purpose.

Comment: The markup does not support all features of *html*

Comment: I am having text like this <p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height: normal; margin: 0in 0in 10pt;"><span style="font-family: Calibri;">sample text.<span style="mso-spacerun: yes;">&nbsp; </span>. Style line height is not reading by jasper. Do we have any work around for this